# Angular 2 service: Why the private member is undefined?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Trying to figure out why If I set a private member of a service, when I get back to that service I will find out that the member is undefined.

```
getResult (): Observable<result[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();

    // save the data in the service
    this.data = body;

    return body || { };
  }
```

From another function in the service, when I try to read this.data it is undefined. Why?

```
    getData() {

         this.data // undefeind !!!!
}
```

From a component there is a call to the service to getData onInit:

```
 this.myService.getResult()
      .subscribe(res => {this.data= res;
        },
        error => {
          console.log("error on getData function: " + error);
        }
      );
```

Comment: async data.. the response may not be set yet..

Comment: it did. first thing is getResult and without it getData will never happen

Comment: can you add the code where it is called? getResult and getData

Comment: Call it like .map(this.extractData.bind(this)), same with handleError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access `this` within the passed method you need to bind `this`

```ts
.map(this.extractData.bind(this))
```

`bind(this)` is IMHO more convenient for this use case than `() =>  {}` because it works, no matter how many parameters need to be passed. With arrow functions all parameters need to be repeated twice.

Comment: This answer is both correct and to the point. I will just add that this has nothing to do with `private`

Comment: Perhaps the docs should be updated as the currently all show the error prone code that breaks if this is used. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Comment: There is no need for `bind` if `this.` isn't used, and in `extractData` I never have seen `this` being used so far. It's also basic JS/TS knowledge entirely unrelated to Angular.

Comment: I know, but it is very easy for a bug to creep in because it is a method. If it were me, I would never use a method for that handler precisely for that reason. I would extract it as a free standing function within the module closure (not-exported). For member functions, using bind, or `=>` is good practice in general as they can be changed subtly to use instance state. I agree it is not necessary to do this but it is a reasonable practice.

Comment: I wouldn't use TS or JS, but Dart instead. Ah, wait, that's what I'm already doing ;-)

Comment: LOL, I know, and you are getting your own rewrite :p. If only TS could get a rewrite that was idiomatic. For example it would use generic types to get type safety on dynamic form objects.

Comment: The journey just has begun. TS has room for improvement and I'm sure they'll try to figure something out, but it's not that easy with JS inheritage.

Comment: Personally, I don't care for Dart, but I think it was mistreated by google. A project with that ambitious a target needs serious support and it is sad how small the user base is.

Comment: Yes it is. TypeScript <=> JavaScript. Semantics are identical. One is static representation for the other. I feel that you guys (Angular team) treat TypeScript as if it is Java-like, when it has never been. It simply describes the dynamic behavior of JavaScript in a static manner. For example. TypeScript has no nominal types! I am not just saying that, it is in the TypeScript definition and project goals as well.

Comment: Angular 2 code looks like it wants to be written in Java. That makes me said because... well... who would ever want to use Java for anything

Comment: Much love nevertheless

Comment: I don't really want to start a Dart discussion here, but ;-) you can't build a huge user base within 3 years, even when you're Google, and the target moved quite a lot since they started, but the user base is continually growing. TS wouldn't play such a big role without Angular, Angular was a bit too early for Dart. For Dart Flutter could be the great breakthrough. We'll see. I have no intention to convince anyone to switch, I just try to correct false impressions about Dart when I perceive comments as such.

Comment: "TS wouldn't play such a big role without Angular". Indeed, I just wish you ya'll would follow the TypeScript recommendations (for third parties not contrib) from the handbook instead of teaching everyone how to write the most verbose and least type safe typescript :(

Comment: Honestly, the worst two things are 1: use of `any`, and 2: use of classes as model types via type assertions, instead of interfaces via type assertions. People think their instanceof tests will work with these types, it is a failure point that explicitly deviates from TS recommendation and leads to problems.

Comment: Again much love

Comment: "I just wish you ya'll would follow the TypeScript recommendations (for third parties not contrib)" I use TS only in Plunker and there I get no feedback about that. I'm myself also only interested in Angular itself, but not in TS. I see your point though.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your unassuming attitude and your perspective as well. And it's not code that you write that I'm really taking an issue with its code that people on my team will copy and paste from the angular docs. The funny thing about that is that you don't particularly like the language. The thing is that type script works the best when you let type inference do most of the work. The easiest way to do that is to program in a functional style that empathizes values over Control structures and object identity.  That's also where the Synergy between typescript and JavaScript is

Answer (score 1):

@Gunther's solution works.
Another way to solve is to wrap in  arrow functions.

```
getResult (): Observable<result[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map((res)=>this.extractData(res))
      .catch((err)=>this.handleError(err));
  }
```